# syntax highlighting js file to match period in between methods

Tags: javascript, vim, syntax

I am trying to highlight periods in between methods in my javascript file to improve readability. What should I do to accomplish this? I have a file in `.vim/after/syntax/javascript`. How do I set up my `syntax match` and `hi` colors to accomplish this? I am currently using *monokai* colorscheme and these are my js plugins in my .vimrc

```
Plugin 'moll/vim-node'
Plugin 'pangloss/vim-javascript'
Plugin 'crusoexia/vim-javascript-lib' " includes syntax hl for mocha
Plugin 'elzr/vim-json'
Plugin 'mxw/vim-jsx'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following commands will highlight dots with the style `MethodDot`:

```
hi MethodDot ctermfg=Red cterm=bold guifg=Red gui=bold                                    
syn match MethodDot "\(\w\)\@<=\.\(\w\)\@="
```

To be highlighted, the dots must be surrounded by a word character `\w`. The result is:

```
one.method();                  // dot is highlighted
name = person.fullName();      // dot is highlighted
A sentece. Text.               // dots are not highlighted
```

Comment: Thanks Sergio. Where should I place the lines? I currently wrote them in .vim/after/syntax/javascript.vim but I do not see any changes..

Comment: That directory should be fine but use auto commands. For example: `autocmd BufEnter *.js hi MethodDot ...` and `autocmd BufEnter *.js syn match MethodDot ...`

Comment: hi Sergio, thanks for your patience. I wrote this `autocmd BufEnter *.js hi MethodDot ctermfg=Red cterm=bold guifg=Red gui=bold    
autocmd BufEnter *.js syn match MethodDot "\(\w\)\@<=\.\(\w\)\@="` in the file I told you and I still cannot see any changes.

Comment: You could print sourced files with `:scriptnames` do you see  .vim/after/syntax/javascript.vim ?

Comment: No I do not see it nor do I see `.vim/after/syntax/xml.vim`. I do see these

Comment: `~/.vim/bundle/vim-node/ftdetect/node.vim
  ~/.vim/bundle/vim-javascript/ftdetect/javascript.vim
  ~/.vim/bundle/vim-json/ftdetect/json.vim
  ~/.vim/bundle/vim-jsx/ftdetect/javascript.vim`

Comment: Files in ~/.vim/after should be sourced at startup. This could mean that your runtimepath option is overwritten by some of your plugins. A possible solution is to add the line `rtp+=~/.vim/after` to your .vimrc. Alternatively add  the auto-commands of earlier comments to ~/.vim/bundle/vim-jsx/ftdetect/javascript.vim.

Comment: this actually works on any `.js` file... but does not work with React projects. Specifically, this does not work inside any method definitions in a react project... for example, periods are not highlighted inside render() {} method definitions. any idea what is going on?